# Why does +xp shows when upgrading unit?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-brave-new-world

Every time I upgrade a unit +xp shows where  is some number. What does this mean? It certainly does not get added to the units xp.

Answer (score 8):

It's a minor UI bug due to how units are upgraded. The new unit is created, the old unit's properties are copied over, and the old unit is destroyed. Thus, the game sees XP being added to the new unit and reports it in the UI.

Comment: That is always what I figured as well

Comment: It actually creates the new unit before deleting the old one, so they briefly exist at the same time. The easiest way to see this is when upgrading between two units that use the same resource; for a moment, it will be double-counted against your total.

Comment: This is right, it's been this way since 4. I can confirm it's still around 6 as well